# deep learning: what if i have a picture that is labeled with a class but it is not of that class

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

im trying to figure out a question, the thing is that im working with a big dataset of pictures, the key idea is that almost all the pictures have just 1 person in it, every class should represent a different person but for some reason, lets say 1 of 1000 pictures in every class has a face that does not belong to that class(is not the same person that is on the other pics in that class) actually the person miss labeled is not from any class. here is my question: what happens on the learning process?, the convnet learns that that face is not useful for the task? or it generate some kind of error? i ask this because i need to know if i need to remove these "noisy" pictures for better performance, or if it is the case, the error would be neglectable. Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misleading targets will definitely add noise to your data. It will make training much more unstable if you have significant amount of incorrectly labeled data. Although, in your case, if you have 1/1000 ratio of incorrectly labeled data, unless you are using weighted classes, it won't much affect training.

By the way, if you are trying to create model that classifies a person by
face image, you might want to create other features, like eyes position, skin color, etc.